# Why sublist item wont change and commit using Client Script 2.X

Tags: suitescript, suitescript2.0

When my Client Script runs the sublist items value wont change and commit.

I have a code deployed in a Credit Note that changes the sublist item value and commits it for every line it has. Below is my Client script Code.

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.0
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */


define(['N/currentRecord','N/log'], function(currentRecord,log) {
  function pageInit(context) {
    var newRec = context.currentRecord;
    var isConverted = newRec.getValue({
      fieldId: 'custbody15'
    });

    if (isConverted === true) {
      var numLines = newRec.getLineCount({
        sublistId: 'item'
      })

      var totalLines = (numLines - 1);


      for (var i = 0; i <= totalLines; i++) {
        var currLine = newRec.selectLine({
          sublistId: 'item',
          line: i
        });
        log.debug({title: 'Line Selected', details: currLine })

        currLine.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'item',
          fieldId: 'item',
          value: 836,
          ignoreFieldChange: true,
          forceSyncSourcing: false
        });

        currLine.commitLine({
          sublistId: 'item'
        });
        log.debug({title: 'is committed?', details: 'Yes' })
      }
    }

  }
  return {
    pageInit: pageInit
  };
});
```

But when I do console scripting it works every time. below is my console scripting

```
require(['N/currentRecord'], function(currentRecord){
  var currRecObj = currentRecord.get();
  var lineObj = currRecObj.getLineCount({
    sublistId: 'item'
  });
  var actLines = lineObj - 1;
  for (i = 0; i <= actLines; i++) {
    var curLineObj = currRecObj.selectLine({
      sublistId: 'item',
      line: i
    });
    curLineObj.setCurrentSublistValue({
      sublistId: 'item',
      fieldId: 'item',
      value: 836,
      ignoreFieldChange: true,
      forceSyncSourcing: false
    });
    curLineObj.commitLine({
      sublistId: 'item'
    });
  }
});
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What are the log.debug() outputs? You have 2 of them in your client script, what do they show?

Comment: in the 1st debug I wanted to log the current line but what I get is the context record I believe. e.g.

id: ""
type: "creditmemo"
isDynamic: true
something like that in the 1st debug. 

in the 2nd debug it just print "is it commited yes when executed". (This is for me to know  that the line commit also ran).

Comment: The only difference I'm seeing is that in your console script you use the `'N/currentRecord'` module to get the current record, while in your client script you use the `context.currentRecord`. So why don't you just try to use the module in your client script?

Comment: How are the credit notes being entered when your client script executes?  If you haven't already, you can use the javascript console and console.log to check values of custbody15 and the line.

Comment: It's okay now guys. Thanks for the suggestions upon further checking it was having conflicts to one of the client scripts. so as a solution I put my script on top of the deployment list